# jQuery KeyPress limiting my input on TextArea

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have this code:

```
$('#typer').keypress(function(e){

            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

            if (code == '13') {
                $.sound.play("cr.wav",{timeout:1000}); 
            } else if (code == '8') {
                $.sound.play("del.wav",{timeout:1000});
            } else if (code == '27') {
                $.sound.play("asswipe.wav",{timeout:1000});
            } else {
                $.sound.play("key.wav",{timeout:1000});
            }
        });
```

Now, for some reason - I can only type ***one character*** in this box. The sound plays once and then nothing more.

This works fine in IE... Just FireFox...

Plugin link: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?r=5750

Has ANYONE ever used this plugin....?

Comment: 2 Things: 1) just use `e.which`, [jQuery normalizes it already](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L468), no need to check both.  2) Which plugin are you using for sound? The issue is in that code.

Comment: Do you mean the box is losing focus after you type the first character, or the box is limiting you to a single character?  I would hazard a guess that your `$.sound` plugin is taking focus away and giving it to whatever plays the sound.

Comment: @Nick Craver - I am using the jQuery sound plugin (no flash), utilising the `$.sound.play` function

Comment: @Andy E's Head - That's what I thought, but there is nothing on the page for the focus to go to.

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Always post a *link* to the plugin :) This is like saying "the autocomplete plugin", there are different ones available, you need to be specific, a link is best.

Comment: Well, I updated it... and no one answers, I'm finding this more and more with SO... People want answers but never give help... always the same people helping out (which i dont have a problem with, but come on you people!! YOU KNOW WHO YOU ARE!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, e.which is a number, not a string, so you should lose the single quotes: use `code == 13`, not `code == '13'`.  You might be better served by a switch statement (though that's just a matter of preference).

Second, I don't think the problem is with the plugin.  Without using the plugin, this has the same problem:

```
$('#typer').keypress(function(e) {
    var snd = $('<embed hidden="true" loop="false" src="key.wav" autostart="true" height="0" />');
    snd.appendTo("body");
    setTimeout(function() { snd.remove(); }, 1000);
});
```

It seems that FF and Chrome do not deal well with having `<embed>` tags added to them dynamically.  You may want to look for a different plugin, one that doesn't use the  tag.  I'm not a fan of flash, but there are probably some plugins out there that use it, and that work well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try keydown instead of keypress?  I've had lots of problems using keypress working on a RPG sprite character movement project with numbers not matching to the expected key and just abandoned it altogether in favor of keydown.

If that doesn't work I can look into replicating your environment.

**Edit:**
This seems to work for me (Chrome & Firefox 3.6):
http://resopollution.com/experiments/sound/sound.html

I did notice ONCE that the page simply opened up the audio file (seems buggy), but can't replicate it.  Perhaps that is what you are experiencing...  It works fine now for me.

If you still experience problems...

**Alternative 1**
You may be able to change the invisible  tag (in the plugin) to an invisible  that links to a page which has your  wav file with autoplay on and no loop.

**Alternative 2**
Use an html5/flash option.
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: I'm afraid I tried this already, I've also tried keyup and all the other little bits n pieces, it just has me confused :(

Comment: I've tested it and updated my answer.  Please let me know if the link I provided works for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for having a go at this, the code you provided works fine in IE, but with firefox 3.6.6 it makes the http connection to download the wav but no sound plays at all :( I'll have no hair by the end of this project!! lol

Answer (score 0):

```
// play a sound from the url, on a track, stopping any sound already running on that track
    $.sound.play(url, {
     track: "track1"
    });
```

Above is the documentation from the plugin you're using.

Did you try playing each sound on a new track?

I'd create a new name for each track on every keypress function and assign the sound src to that new track.

Comment: (thinking along the lines of sound layering in flash)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right way to do it (without being told to use flash by EVERYONE :). I now have the line: `$.sound.play("del.wav",{track: "track2", timeout:1000});` but it says that the syntax is slightly b0rked :(

Comment: I just tested this: $(function(){ $.sound.play("catpurr2.wav",{track: "track2", timeout:1000}); without error. Did you load the jQuery library before the plugin? And for the syntax problem, will be helpful if you know exactly where it is coming from. Using something like IE development toolbar debugger will be useful for script debugging - F12 on IE.